# How to debug certain errors in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Have been wanting to ask for this for awhile now... so frequently when I run a test I'll get an error like this:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/features/admin/2_email_maintenances_spec.rb:32 -b
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/features/admin/2_email_maintenances_spec.rb"=>[32]}}

An error occurred in an after hook
  ActionView::Template::Error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
  occurred at /Users/jamesdong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:45:in `__temp__079636b65707f53747162747'

F

Failures:
```

What's the best way to figure out where in the code the `ActionView::Template::Error` is coming from? Running the spec with a full backtrace (`-b`) doesn't really help since that debugs why the test failed, not the errors that I get in the code. Also going to the file referenced doesn't help, because like... I get the error, I just want to know where in MY code the method was called.

Answer (score 0):

RSpec-core lets you filter out individual gems:

```
# arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("active_record")
```

RSpec-rails provides an additional option to filter out all the "rails" gems (ActiveRecord, ActionPack etc.):

```
# Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
```

Comment: i don't think i want to filter them out though... i want to find out what's causing them?

Comment: Filtering out the rails gems makes it much easier to find the error in your code as it will be at the top of the stack trace.